# In Javascript, is Array.join really Array.prototype.join?

Tags: javascript

I wonder why even in the Javascript Definitive Guide 6th ed, O'Reilly, [p. 149 - 150](http://books.google.com/books?id=6TAODdEIxrgC&lpg=PA149&ots=obbpJQLwUC&dq=Array.join%20definitive&pg=PA150#v=onepage&q=Array.join%20definitive&f=false), it keeps on using `Array.join()` or `Array.concat()`.  Should it be `Array.prototype.join()` instead?

But while Chrome doesn't have `Array.join` defined, Firefox actually does, and it can be invoked by `Array.join(array, string)`.  The difference might be important as one is a class method and the other is an instance method.  I wonder why that is?

The book kept on using `Array.join` even in the Core Javascript Reference docs, but maybe it meant `Array.prototype.join`, and also, it seems to suggest that `Array` has a `length` property, but it really should also be a property of `Array.prototype`, and is `Array.prototype.length`?

By the way, it seems that Firefox's implementation of `Array.prototype.join` can be

```
Array.prototype.join = function(s) {
    return Array.join(this, s);
}
```

but I don't see that usually being done (defining a class method that can be invoked on an instance).

Comment: Isn't it the case that methods are defined on the prototype but executed on the "class"?

Comment: If you mean `[].join`, then it's the prototype one. `Array.join` is indeed misleading. I've also seen `Array#join` as a notation for such methods.

Comment: I think it's just a bad choice of notation/terminology on the part of O'Reilly.  The introduction to that section explicitly states that the methods discussed are on the prototype object; for some reason, however, they use the incorrect way of indicating that as you note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FireFox puts *a version* of prototyped methods on the related constructor.

This isn't part of the ECMAScript standard, but rather is part of the specific JavaScript superset of ECMAScript.

The book should make that distinction, unless the book is talking specifically about the JavaScript extensions.

Keep in mind that JavaScript !== ECMAScript. ECMAScript is the language standard, and JavaScript is an implementation of the 3rd edition of that standard, and includes a superset of functionality not specified by the standard.